# In app billing 'Not Eligible' payment method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I uploaded an apk to playstore(beta testing) few days ago and I have enabled inapp purchase for user.But whenever i try to test the purchase, I get following error.

[image]
In app purchase is working for other apps so my device account has no problem.
How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey dd619 , have you find out what is issue? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test your app using by marking your Google email to a test account (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup), rather than using your real bank account.